# How to retrieve tweets in given time interval using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume

i want to retrieve tweets in given time interval , say from 2015/03/26 to 2015/03/01 using flume agent. How to configure flume.confg in order to achieve this scenario ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: i have retrieved tweets using flume agent, right now i need to retrieve the tweets in a given specific time interval say between 2015/03/26 to 2015/03/01, so to achieve this what i have to make  changes in the flume configuration  file, if not how can i over come this scenario